# Blowfish шифрование между JavaScript и PHP

Tags: mcrypt, blowfish, php, javascript

На стороне JS работает библиотека blowfish.js, она отлично шифрует и расшифровывает, с ней проблем нет. На стороне PHP для расшифровки использую `mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, pack('H*',$str), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)`, она отлично расшифровывает то, что зашифровал blowfish.js. Но вот как зашифровать на PHP, я не знаю (`mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)` выдает какую-то хрень). Может, кто подскажет, как правильно написать `mcrypt_encrypt()` для blowfish, или, может, на PHP есть альтернатива mcrypt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так вроде:

```
unpack('H*', mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $code, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```